# Find three distinct positive integers ,, such that number one less than the product of any two is divisible by the third

Tags: elementary-number-theory

X < Y < Z

1. X . Y = Z.M1 + 1
2. Y . Z = X.M2 + 1
3. Z . X = Y.M3 + 1

How do I get the 3 numbers?

Comment: My first try, which might **fail** to lead anywhere constructive, would be **elbow grease**.  Manually look for solutions where (for example) $X \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, and see where this leads.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me "prime the pump" here.

Render

$\dfrac{ab-1}{c}=k$

$\dfrac{ac-1}{b}=l$

$\dfrac{bc-1}{a}=m$

and multiply these together to get

$\dfrac{(ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1)}{abc}=klm$

Expand the product in the numerator and identify terms that are multiples of the denominator$abc$ to get

$(abc-a-b-c)+\dfrac{ab+ac+bc-1}{abc}=klm$

from which

$\dfrac{ab+ac+bc-1}{abc}=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}-\dfrac{1}{abc}=klm-abc+a+b+c$

The left side must be positive and the right side is a whole number, so the common value above us a positive whole number. From this conclude that

$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}>1$

which forces $a,b,c$ to be small.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was very helpful for this problem.